# Disabling Pop-Up Tool-Tips in Adobe Reader

Tags: adobe-reader

Is there any way to disable these annoying tool-tips in adobe reader? They come up every time I open a document. I am using Adobe Reader X.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Edit > Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>) and select the General category. Uncheck

> show me messages when I launch Reader

And that should be it.

Answer (score 6):

That should be it, and yet I still get the bubble that says:

> Click on Tools to convert PDF documents to Word or Excel.

I found the answer [**here**](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3992945) and I quote:

> "If you scroll to the top right of this box, you should see a cross button. Once you click that, you should not see the message again."

That was it.

Comment: Yes, but in the same page somebody says...  "Yes, but that is exactly what I am hoping to avoid having to do every time i open a PDF doc... How can i avoid seeing this bubble and clicking the cross button every time?
 
Every time I open a new PDF i have to click this bubble. If I open the same PDF doc again, its gone. But when opening a previously un-opened doc, the annoying bubble is back."

Answer (score 2):

It has taken me ages to find out how to disable info bubble for all accounts under Win7 Pro; it worked as follows:

1. Get the info to disable it as Admin, supposedly at a machine level, from: Enterprise Admin Guide http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/preferences.html
2. Do as stated under Administrator (machine level) preferences, that is, logon with Admin privileges, open registry editor regedit.exe, go to key

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\FeatureLockDown

   and add a DWORD in the registry with name `bShowTaskButtonInfoBubble` and value 0, another DWORD with name `bInfobubble` and value 0 is supposed to suppress Tools, Sign and Comments bubbles (I added it too)

So far it worked for all Admin accounts but any standard user account in the machine continued showing the Tools info bubble when opening Reader XI.

As it seems, in addition to DWORDs indicated in Enterprise Admin Guide for HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\AVGeneral, another DWORD is required with name ´sInfoBubbleLastDisplayedTime´ (see http://forums.adobe.com/message/5049074) and with a hard to guess hex value; it worked for me to create a text file with .reg extension containing the text given in that forum as follows (sInfoBubbleLastDisplayedTime hex value all in one line):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\AVGeneral]
"bReaderShowCPDFToolsPaneInfoBubble"=dword:00000000
"bReaderShouldShowInfoBubble"=dword:00000000
"bAppInitialized"=dword:00000001
"sInfoBubbleLastDisplayedTime"=hex:44,3a,32,30,31,33,30,32,30,35,31,31 ,33,34, 31,37,2d,30,36,27,30,30,27,00
"bReaderShowEPDFToolsPaneInfoBubble"=dword:00000000

then, while logged as standard user, clicking on the .reg file includes the values in the registry and does the trick.

I hope it helps someone as desperate as I was until I found this peculiar DWORD value.

Answer (score 2):

In Adobe Acrobat Pro DC you need to uncheck 2 boxes...

1. First location:

   > Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Scroll down and uncheck "Show me messages" when launching Acrobat
2. Second location:

   > Edit -> Preferences -> Accessibility -> Enable assistive technology support

Be sure to hit the OK button on the bottom right of the screen for each location.
On my screen, I had to scroll down to see the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

This same problem began bugging me after a OS change, I found the easy way to disable them, just right clik over the toolbar and uncheck the "Show all tools comments"

Here is a link to the screen capture of the spanish versión, the order of the menú ítems should be the same on all other versions:

[image]